# Add bgcolor attribute to alternating tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm editing an email template that is compiled weekly with an unpredictable number of articles. It's set up so that each additional newsletter articles automatically generates a new table to contain it.

Using css I was able to target every other table to give an appearance of alternating backgrounds

```
body > center > table.cwrapper:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
```

My problem is with how Microsoft Outlook handles it. It doesn't accept that form of css. Other email clients are working fine.

Is there a way I can write a short script that injects the BGCOLOR attribute into every other table thereby getting rid of my need for that line of css?

```
<table width="800" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" class="cwrapper">
    <tr>
        <td id="dnn_ctr392_ContentPane" align="left" class="DNNAlignleft">  
            <%=oRs("ArticleText")%>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please share the html

Comment: I've added it but as I stated it's literally just a plain jane table.

Comment: As far as I know, majority of email clients don't deal with CSS, you need to put inline this without <style> tag. Anyway, did you tried switching property to `background: #f2f2f2`

Comment: Writing the script is easy, but i doubt that Outlook executes JS from e-mails…

Comment: The way our system works is we set this up at a "webpage" then just copy from the view source and paste it into the html email client. Not the best way to do it but I have no control over that portion. So my goal is to have it so the script runs when the "webpage" is opened and auto inserts the BGcolor attribute so that by the time the source is copy/pasted into the email client the attributes are already there.

Comment: I have tried both background and background-color properties, which is why I am now looking for a non css solution.

Comment: Well, there is no _non CSS_ solution, as CSS is what one use to style html elements.

Comment: For HTML5, use `<table style="background-color:red">` ... for older, use old _bgcolor_ attribute `<table bgcolor="#FF0000">`

Comment: @LGSon Yes, I understand that those are the two options to set the background color. My question is about writing a script that will inject a bgcolor into every other table on the page.

Comment: If you mean in the mail client, then no, as more or less no linked resources (other than images) is allowed and will be stripped out. Email clients are a little bit more cautious than webbrowsers.

Comment: Sorry to repeat myself, if you look a few comments above maybe it explains it better. This is first compiled as a webpage. I then do a view source, copy all html and paste it into a piece of software that sends mass emails out in html form. The mail client does not need to run the script. The script runs when the webpage is first loaded, before the view source process.

Comment: @KristenVogler this will not work as a method. the HTML Source code will not contain the script executed changes. So, for example, if you add a background color via JS, it will not be reflected in the source code, it gets applied after the page is loaded, during the time it is rendered. JS does not actually change the source, only reads from it. You will need to manually edit the HTML to include the proper markup before entering into the email body.

Comment: @Twisty Thank you...now I don't have to write that :)

Comment: @KristenVogler modern browsers do have a method for this. If you use `Inspect Element`, the browser will reveal the new, or rendered, markup. This will include the added attributes from scripts. So this would be the way I would advise capturing the HTML code you want.

Comment: @Twisty Thank you for the information, that is a good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I would propose is not a change to your code, but a change to the method you use to extract the code. It is the difference between View Source and Inspect Element in a browser.

I will use FierFox as an example.

When you right-click and select View Source, you will see the original Source Code that was downloaded by the browser. This will **not** include changes via client side scripts, such as JavaScript.

If you right-click and use Inspect Element, FireFox will open it's development tools and reveal the currently rendered markup. This is what you want to be able to provide a copy to an Email.

To do this, take the following steps:

- Right-click an element on a web page and select Inspect Element.
- In the HTML Pane, scroll up and find `<HTML>` tag.
- Right click on `<HTML>` and select Copy > Outer HTML
- Navigate to your email body and Paste

[image: FireFox Inspect Element Demo]

You will get a complete copy of the HTML including all the changes made by JavaScript.

As you mentioned, outlook will not like CSS. So when you adjust your Script, use the `.css()` feature of jQuery. This will add `style` attribute to elements, which is what Outlook will look for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, because the css is in a style tag an not inline this will not work. But I am hopeful it will if I can figure out a way to make it inline with with javascript.

Comment: For anyone else, this is the very short script I used: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body > center > table.cwrapper:nth-child(odd)').css("background", "#f2f2f2");
});
</script>

Comment: You beat me to my own comment! :D That's exactly what you need.

Comment: @KristenVogler You can also do: `$('table.cwrapper tr:odd').css("background", "#f2f2f2");`